# groovy + jpa + maven = loader constraint violation for javax/xml/transform/Source

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, jpa, groovy

if I create a JPA EntityManager from a groovy script I get these error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/transform/Source"
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:89)
at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:168)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:310)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
...
```

If I create the EntityManager from a main method in a java class it will work.

I use mave, the dependencies in my pom looks like this:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.3-606.jdbc3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Can someone tell me what I have make wrong and how can I solve it?

Medrod

Answer (score 0):

the javax.xml.transform.Source is now part of JDK 6. it seems that some dependency (likely Hibernate) has an indirect dependency to the xml-apis jar file (which in fact also contains the java.xml.* classes). You have to find that dependency and exclude xml-apis.